# How to set a variable as a value from a csv file with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I'm trying to utilize values from a .csv file as variables in a Powershell script. My .csv looks something like this:

```
| Date     | Site     | Mileage Start | Mileage Stop |
| -------- | -------- |    -----      |              |
| 11/09/22 | Town1    |    21509      |     21564    |
|          | Town2    |    21564      |     21583    |
```

or as a pure .csv:

```
Date,Site,Mileage Start,Mileage Stop,Temp,Sky,Soil,Time In,Time Out,,,,,,,,,
11/9/2022,Town1,21509,21564,71,Sunny,Dry,1:00,1:45,,,,,,,,,
,Town2,21564,21583,55,Cloudy,Wet,2:45,3:30,,,,,,,,,
```

I want to define variables for all of the information in the table. I've read through the website man pages for Get-Content and Import-Csv. It seems like the right track but I'm unable to determine how to use them. I'm new to powershell scripting, I don't understand much.

I tried to define the entire table as a variable and the parse it ie:
`$inputs = import-csv -path`

But once I had this I couldn't figure out how to remove only the data

Comment: "I want to define variables for all of the information in the table." - for which purpose?

Comment: [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) returns a stream (array) of objects, each of which represents a data row from the CSV. The property names and values correspond to the column names and values. Please [edit] your question to describe what you want to do with the data.